# Chamada de pagina usando Classe no Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou trabalhando em um plugin e criei uma classe para exibir a opção no menu lateral e o conteudo da pagina relacionado a este plugin, porém não sei como posso fazer para exibir o conteudo dentro da mesma.

Antes eu fazia da seguinte maneira;

```
function add_birthday_to_menu() {
    add_menu_page('Clientes',
        'Clientes',
        'manage_options',
        'birthday-celebrate',
        'birthday_celebrate_page', // A função de callback 
        'dashicons-universal-access',
        6);
}

function birthday_celebrate_page() { ...
```

Desta maneira o callback procuraria uma função com o mesmo nome passado e executaria, porém estas 2 funções agora estão dentro de uma classe...

```
class Birthday_celebrate
{
   public function add_birthday_to_menu()
   {
       add_menu_page('Clientes',
        'Clientes',
        'manage_options',
        'birthday-celebrate',
        'birthday_celebrate_page', // (?)
        'dashicons-universal-access',
        6);
   }

   public function birthday_celebrate_page() { ...
```

Para adicionar o menu usando a classe eu fiz;

```
add_action('admin_menu', array('Birthday_celebrate', 'add_birthday_to_menu'));
```

Mas como eu faço para que a função `add_menu_page` procure o callback dentro da própria classe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sempre que estiver referenciando um método dentro de uma classe basta você passar o callback como `array` em que o primeiro elemento é o próprio objeto:

```
class Birthday_celebrate
{
   public function add_birthday_to_menu()
   {
       add_menu_page('Clientes',
        'Clientes',
        'manage_options',
        'birthday-celebrate',
        array( $this, 'birthday_celebrate_page' ),
        'dashicons-universal-access',
        6);
   }

   public function birthday_celebrate_page() { ...
```

outras opções que funcionam:

```
// para métodos estáticos
array( 'Birthday_celebrate::birthday_celebrate_page' )

// referenciando o namespace
array( __NAMESPACE__.'::Birthday_celebrate', 'birthday_celebrate_page' )
```

E tem outras formas. Basta que seja um array ou string que possa ser interpretado por [call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.call-user-func.php) ou [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.call-user-func-array.php)